# I am using emacs on window OS, possible to use multiple monitor?

Tags: emacsclient

I got 2 monitors, but emacs can only use one, can I use both of them, so that I could split windows cross both monitors? so If I want to create 2 windows, then each monitor could show me one windows.

Comment: You're probably asking two things. Please reformat your post in a more proper way. And yes, it's possible. Create an emacsclient instance on the anohter display.

Comment: Check out this link too, to learn how to position the frames once you create them in your .emacs. I don't know how to automatically position a second frame on a second monitor (never tried it), but you could always create the second frame automatically, and then manually drag it over if necessary. That's what I do. [This link contains code, too.](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21815/how-can-i-arrange-several-frames-at-fixed-relative-positions/21854#21854)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5766)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question, try `C-x 5 2` (the default binding for `make-frame-command`) to create a new frame. You can have several frames and position them on your various monitors however you like.

The `C-x 5` prefix has several other commands for dealing with frames. Try `C-x 5 C-h` for a list. See the Emacs manual section on [Frames](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html) for more information.